# How to copy a file into directory without losing the previous contents of directory in ant?

Tags: ant

Hi this is my code for copying a file from one location to another

```
<copy file="${MyParam}\${files.Sloc}\${files.names}" tofile="..\${cmdname}\${files.Tloc}\${files.names}"> </copy>
```

Although it is copying the file to its destination perfectly but thee problem is it is deleting the the previous directory structure that is if i have

`D:/a/b/c/d/e` and in `e` if i already have `1,2,3,4` as file now if i want to put another file into `e`,instead of placing it into `e` the above task first deletes `D:/a/b/c/d/e`  and all files in `e` and creates new path as `D:/a/b/c/d/e` and places the new file there so i am losing everything out.is there anyway out please help.tried some things but they did not work our.

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong. 
I created this example:

```
<project default="run">
<target name="run">
    <!-- create new directory with some files -->
    <delete dir="a/b/c/d/e"/>
    <mkdir dir="a/b/c/d/e"/>
    <touch file="a/b/c/d/e/1"/>
    <touch file="a/b/c/d/e/2"/>

    <!-- list directory contents -->
    <fileset id="e.contents.before" dir="a/b/c/d/e"/>
    <property name="prop.e.contents.before" refid="e.contents.before"/>
    <echo>Before copy: ${prop.e.contents.before}</echo>

    <!-- copy some file to directory -->
    <copy file="build.xml" tofile="a/b/c/d/e/build.xml"> </copy>

    <!-- list directory contents -->
    <fileset id="e.contents.after" dir="a/b/c/d/e"/>
    <property name="prop.e.contents.after" refid="e.contents.after"/>
    <echo>After  copy: ${prop.e.contents.after}</echo>
</target>
```

The output is using Ant 1.8.2 on Linux:

Buildfile: /tmp/t/build.xml

run:
   [delete] Deleting directory /tmp/t/a/b/c/d/e
    [mkdir] Created dir: /tmp/t/a/b/c/d/e
    [touch] Creating /tmp/t/a/b/c/d/e/1
    [touch] Creating /tmp/t/a/b/c/d/e/2
     [echo] Before copy: 1;2
     [copy] Copying 1 file to /tmp/t/a/b/c/d/e
     [echo] After  copy: 1;2;build.xml

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 0 seconds

Comment: hey yes actually i was selectin the destination directory which was not the desired one so it creating a new one at new location...Now i changed it and it is working fine..